# looping and decrementing sum

Tags: javascript, loops

I can't figure out why my decrement sum won't work. It will work fine for the incrementing part, but if the first array value is greater than the second it doesn't seem to run:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
  var sum = 0;
  if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
    for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
      sum += i;
      console.log(sum);
    }
  } else if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    for (var j = arr[1]; j >= arr[0]; j--) {
      sum += j;
      console.log("sec", sum);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

sumAll([9, 3]);
```

Comment: Its because in the for loop you have the condition j >= arr[0] but in the else if you have condition (arr[0] > arr[1]). My point is, the for loop never gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already explained in the comment, but here is the code:

Its because in the for loop you have the condition `j >= arr[0]` but in the else if you have condition `(arr[0] > arr[1])` and because of that the for loops never gets executed.

Here is the working code:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
  var sum = 0;
  if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
    for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
      sum += i;
      console.log(sum);
    }
  } else if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    for (var j = arr[0]; j >= arr[1]; j--) {

      sum += j;

      console.log("sec", sum);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

alert(sumAll([9, 3]););
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0],arr[1]);
  var sum=0;
  if(arr[0] < arr[1]){
    for(var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++  ){

      sum += i;
      console.log(sum);

    } 
  } else if(arr[0] > arr[1]) {

    for(var j = arr[1]; j <= arr[0]; j++  ){

      sum += j;

      console.log("sec",sum);
    }

  }

  return sum;
}

sumAll([9,3]);
```

All I did was make the loop end when the number is less than or equal to the greatest number in the array.